# Double Inclusion Questions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

First year computer science student here at a French university. I have studied maths in English for the most part of my life, so I am enduring a few challenges understanding this very theoric math. I am doing my best to find English videos on Youtube but no luck. I dont think Double Inclusion is the same term in English, so that may be why.

Anyways, I have been asked to use Double Inclusion to solve the following:

[image: Regular Set]

[image: Asking me to demonstrate De Morgan theories using Double Inclusion]

Any help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

"Double inclusion" means showing that $X\subseteq Y$
and $Y\subseteq X$, in order to yield $X=Y$.